# jquery dynamically getting class on click of the each block and focus after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> I am trying to get the class on click of each block as the content will
>   be changing on search of each product dynamically, and after ajax call
>   the same class which i have got when clicked should add focus to it.

```
code : 
$('#somecontainer').on('click',function(e) {   
    var $target = $(e.target);   
    if ($target.hasClass("dynamic class")) {
        // same class has to focus().
    }
});
```

In Application View Example :

![enter image description here][1]

Code Screen-Shot :
![enter image description here][2]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "add focus to it"?

Comment: Kindly post your html

Comment: @Robby: once the ajax is loaded successfully, the page scrolls down, so for avoiding that im trying to catch the class and focusing on the same block where i clicked. for accessibility users its difficult to understand where they have clicked.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I think my answer should do the trick.

Comment: @JananiM : HTML is dynamicaly generated, it may contain any of the elements like div, p, span.

Comment: here "var $target = $(e.target);" use "this" instead of "e.target" so it would be "var $target = $(this);"

Comment: do you need the select 's & input[type='text'] class.

Comment: @JananiM : select box is open(options are displayed on the flow) and it doesnot have any class, so im trying to get the element and trying to focus, rest for the elements its working fine..

Comment: I could not get that what you mean by focus. Kindly check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxtau2da/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="somecontainer">
    <div class="dynamic1">1</div>
    <div class="dynamic2">2</div>
    <div class="dynamic3">3</div>
    <div class="dynamic4">4</div>
    <div class="dynamic5">5</div>
    <div class="dynamic6">6</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#somecontainer').on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var clazz = $target.attr('class');

    $('.' + clazz).first().attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
});
```

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/puqejq2z/3/).

Comment: Updated. Apparently `DIV` elements don't accept focus unless the `tabindex` is set. Alternatively, you could use `animate` to scroll to the `DIV` in question.

Comment: how about on click of the element adding tabindex and giving focus to it. again if the next click is triggered, will remove the previous clicked tabindex and focus, and will add to current clicked element

Comment: this is working perfectly for elements which are having classes, 
sorry my bad, i din't notice that there are select box options and checkbox as well which is not having any class.

Comment: Do they have IDs? Names? If you don't have anything to identify them with, it's gonna get tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60591/discussion-between-syd-and-robby-cornelissen).

Answer (score 0):

You question is not accurate for your purpose. But rather than handling click event of container,you can simply handle click event of product block as follow (each product blocks have to be set base static class as product):

```
 <div class='product dynamic1'></div>
 <div class='product dynamic2'></div>

 $('#somecontainer .product').on('click',function(e) {   
    //implementation
 });
```

or each product is div element without inner child element, you can handle as follow:

```
 $('#somecontainer div').on('click',function(e) {   
    //implementation
 });
```

try sample at : http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/8z75c7f4/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="somecontainer">
   <div class="dynamic1">1</div>
   <span class="dynamic2">2</span>
   <p class="dynamic3">3</p>
   <div class="dynamic4">4</div>
   <span class="dynamic5">5</span>
   <p class="dynamic6">6</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#somecontainer > *").click(function(){
       alert($(this).attr('class'));
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#somecontainer > *{
width: 100px; height:100px; background:#ccc;
margin:3px; clear:both;
}
```